# How do I script making a backup copy of a spreadsheet and its values not its formulas to an archive folder?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, backup

I am new to google app scripts and I have been looking for a way to back up a sheet. I am currently using.

DriveApp.getFileById("146qFnrQoNPBcDhV6QB0bscHFp8TquXJoAC1qg‌​_esy4E").makeCopy("D‌​ailyArchive" + Date() + " backup");

The problem is its making a daily backup and those backups are updating just like the original and I just want to make a backup of the values so I have a archive. In my sheet I am importing data from a jail roster. http://www.kitsapgov.com/sheriff/incustody/jailwebname.xml

Comment: im actually using

Comment: DriveApp.getFileById("146qFnrQoNPBcDhV6QB0bscHFp8TquXJoAC1qg_esy4E").makeCopy("DailyArchive" + Date() + " backup");                                                            this is what I am using I ment to put.

Answer (score 0):

Here something quite simple for one sheet (you can adapt it for several sheets)

```
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var data = source.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  var cible = SpreadsheetApp.create(source.getName()+" backup");
  cible.getActiveSheet().getRange(data.getA1Notation()).setValues(data.getValues());
  Logger.log(cible.getId());
  Logger.log(cible.getUrl());
```