# How to copy the format and values, not formulas, of certain cellsin Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a file with quite a few sheets (around 70). I would like to generate an independent file for each sheet whose name corresponds to the name of the sheet. I figured out how to do this part.

Except that I have certain cells that come from a formula and I want to retrieve only the values, not the formulas. I came across this answer:[How to copy format and values, not formulas, when creating a spreadsheet backup in Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58262948/how-to-copy-format-and-values-not-formulas-when-creating-a-spreadsheet-backup/58263965#58263965)

The problem is that my script cannot complete because I exceed the maximum execution time (Error: Exceeded maximum execution time).
Is there a solution to get to the end?

```
function copyEntireSpreadsheet() {
  var id = "###"; // Please set the source Spreadsheet ID.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var srcSheets = ss.getSheets();
  var tempSheets = srcSheets.map(function(sheet, i) {
    var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
    var dstSheet = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName(sheetName + "_temp");
    var src = dstSheet.getDataRange();
    src.copyTo(src, {contentsOnly: true});
    return dstSheet;
  });
  var destination = ss.copy(ss.getName() + " - " + new Date().toLocaleString());
  tempSheets.forEach(function(sheet) {ss.deleteSheet(sheet)});
  var dstSheets = destination.getSheets();
  dstSheets.forEach(function(sheet) {
    var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
    if (sheetName.indexOf("_temp") == -1) {
      destination.deleteSheet(sheet);
    } else {
      sheet.setName(sheetName.slice(0, -5));
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Search in the get Section of the [Range Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) or use [copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)

Comment: First, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. About your question, how about using Sheets API instead of Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp)? But, I cannot know your actual situation including the script and spreadsheet. So, I cannot propose a sample script for directly testing your situation, yet. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: Would you please edit the question to include the script.

Comment: @Tanaike i don't unterstand your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your backups this way

It creates a stringified JSON version of every sheet similar to the files you can retrieve via Apps Script API and it does it fast.  You can go into the file with a text editor and copy the stringified data and paste into  a textbox in a side bar and with a simple code that parses it you can use setValues method to return it to the sheet.  Of course the other possibility is that you could just retrieve the current  version from that google has already saved for you.

```
function copyEntireSpreadsheet() {
  const id = gobj.globals.test1id;
  const dfldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(gobj.globals.folder1id);
  const excl = ["SheetName1","SheetName2"]://excluded sheets
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  const shts = ss.getSheets().filter(sh => !~excl.indexOf(sh.getName()));
  const obj = shts.reduce((a,sh,i) => {
    let n = sh.getName();
    a[n] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
    a.pA.push(n)
    return a;
  },{"SpreadsheetName":ss.getName(),pA:[]});
  const ds = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"yyyyMMdd HHmmss");
  dfldr.createFile(`${obj.SpreadsheetName}-${ds}`,JSON.stringify(obj),MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
}
```

Here's a function I just wrote to restore all of the sheets.  But you can rewrite it to restore just one sheet at a time.

```
function restoreAllSheets() {
  const fid = "your json file id"
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.test1id);
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(fid);
  const data = JSON.parse(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  data.pA.forEach(p => {
    let sh = tss.getSheetByName(p);
    sh.getRange(1,1,data[p].length,data[p][0].length).setValues(data[p]) 
  })
}
```

I also have a sidebar with a textarea where I just copy the json 2d array and I use this javascript function to send in to the server:

```
function loadActiveSheet() {
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(() => {
        document.getElementById("jstxt").value="";
      })
      .loadActivePage(document.getElementById("jstxt").value)
    }
```

and then at the server:

```
function loadActivePage(txt) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = JSON.parse(txt);
  sh.clearContents();
  sh.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

So that way I can just go into the JSON file and get the data for the active page and paste it into the textarea and press a button and it loads the active page.

Look at the file in a text editor and you'll see that it's real easy to read.  It's a pretty simple object.

Comment: I tested your solution: I have an error on the gobj commands (line 2 & 3) -> I corrected it by directly noting the ids of the destination folder and the file.
On the other hand, the resulting document is in Google Doc format and not Google Sheet

Comment: yes those are global variables you need to replace them with your values.

Comment: and how do I then retrieve a Google Sheet file instead of a Google Doc? I didn't really understand what you were recommending.

Comment: I'm saying that you can save all of the data for all sheets in one file that is a stringified object.  You can open the file getDataAsString.  JSON.parse it and use the sheet name as a property to get the 2d array of it's data and then use setValues() to put it back into the sheet.

Comment: where is the file getDataAsString.JSON.parse ? And how can I analyze it? These are procedures that I have never used

Comment: JSON.parse is javascript file.getBlob().getDataAsString() is in DriveAPP.

Comment: ok, thanks. To facilitate creation, if I want not to take all the sheets (some are data that are not necessarily useful to duplicate as an independent file), how should I modify the code?

Comment: Okay now all you have to do is to edit `excl` array.

Comment: I must be bad because I can't do it. I copied your script into Apps script, I run the script: this gives me a single google doc file (.txt) in the folder I specified but no other document (even when searching in my drive). I tried to open the txt file with Google Doc: it loads constantly and without opening. I tried to download the txt then import it into a new google sheet: I got an error message telling me that it can't be opened because it doesn't have the right extension. If I download the txt then try to import it, I get an error because the file to import is too large